# InfluxDB: Continuous query using CASE WHEN not supported. How to get same result (i.e.: using joins?)

Tags: sql, influxdb

Trying to make a [Influx](https://www.influxdata.com/) Continuous Query where certain fields are restricted by a CASE-when. This doesn't seem to be supported.

Is there a way (i.e.: using joins or something) to get a similar result?

Specifically, this is the query I want to get to work (ohclv based on trade-data):

```
SELECT 
        min(price) AS low, 
        max(price) AS high, 
        first(price) AS open, 
        last(price) AS close, 
        sum(amount) AS volume,
        sum(CASE WHEN side="sell" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS volume_sell,
        count(price) AS num_trades,
        count(CASE WHEN side="sell" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_trades_sell
    FROM db..trades
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, would the above result be possible with the new [Flux-language specification](https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/reference/flux/) ?

Comment: Could you divide this query into two queries? The parts with the `case when` could be run separately and the `case when` part will go into a `where side="sell"` clause.

Comment: I would if I could. Alas, the result should be materialized as an Influx continuous query which requires me to build the result using 1 query (afaik)

Comment: Right but can't you have two continuous queries? Or maybe I'm not understanding the task

Comment: Yeah that mights just work. Thanks for looking outside the box :)